# Apache Meecrowave OAuth2 JPA

Tags: jpa, oauth-2.0, openjpa

I succeedeed in creating my own OAuth2 server using JCache as token store but I'm facing an issue when moving to JPA.

My configuration is :

```
                 "--users","test=test",
                 "--roles","test=test",
                 "--oauth2-provider","jpa",
                 "--oauth2-jpa-database-driver","org.h2.Driver",
                 "--oauth2-jpa-database-url","jdbc:h2:mem:oauth",
                 "--oauth2-jpa-database-username","sa",
                 "--oauth2-jpa-database-password",""
```

But I got exception below during OpenJPA bootstrap :

```
here was an error while setting up the configuration plugin option "MetaDataFactory". 
The plugin was of type "org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.PersistenceMappingFactory". 
Setter methods for the following plugin properties were not available in that type: [
org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.tokens.bearer.BearerAccessToken, 
org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.common.OAuthPermission, 
org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.tokens.refresh.RefreshToken, 
org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.grants.code.ServerAuthorizationCodeGrant, 
org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.common.UserSubject]. 
Possible plugin properties are: 
[AnnotationParser, ClasspathScan, FieldOverride, Files, JAR_FILE_URLS, MAPPING_FILE_NAMES, MODE_ALL, MODE_ANN_MAPPING, MODE_MAPPING, MODE_MAPPING_INIT, MODE_META, MODE_NONE, MODE_QUERY, PERSISTENCE_UNIT_ROOT_URL, Repository, Resources, STORE_DEFAULT, STORE_PER_CLASS, STORE_VERBOSE, StoreDirectory, StoreMode, Strict, Types, URLs, XMLAnnotationParser, XMLParser].
Ensure that your plugin configuration string uses key values that correspond to setter methods in the plugin class.
```

I suppose I missed something in configuration...

Any help would be appreciated.

Tx

Answer (score 0):

Using `--oauth2-jpa-properties` you can set any persistence unit properties you want, I guess you will have to override openjpa.MetaDataFactory default value which is set to `jpa(Types=org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.common.Client,org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.common.OAuthPermission,org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.common.UserSubject,org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.grants.code.ServerAuthorizationCodeGrant,org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.tokens.bearer.BearerAccessToken,org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.tokens.refresh.RefreshToken)`.

You can also check if your configuration is properly propagated and if there is no classpath conflict (another persistence.xml with an oauth2 unit?) because I just retested and your configuration seems to work.

Romain

Comment: No other PU and only Meecrowave deps in my pom. While debugging jdbc settings are correctly propagated in props but ConnectionUsername, ConnectionURL are still null. I noticed i have both mee oauth2 & jpa deps, maybe oauth2 is enought ?

Comment: i only have mee oauth2 and httpclient deps in the project and openjpa bootstrap still failed. I dont know how to setup the metadatafactory...

Comment: Hi @ocarrey, `--oauth2-jpa-properties` enables you to configure the full persistence unit, just pass it properties. Can you push a sample projcet reproducing it with h2/hsqldb on github to let us a chance to have a closer look?